# AudioPlayer.Play directive: How to secure the mp3-file, that will be used by alexa

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a skill, that plays a random song when prompted to.

I figured already, that I have to use the `AudioPlayer.Play` directive and give the `audioItem.stream.url` a valid property (e.g. https://test.com/api/getmysong, which returns a streamed mp3 file).

So far, so good. But....

Due to security reasons, I don't want the "public user" be able to access the mp3. How does alexa request the file exactly? Is it also a specific Alexa request I could use to verfiy, the user has the right to request the mp3? Are there any other mechanics I need to use to secure my "mp3"-files?

Answer (score 2):

Your mp3 (file or stream) has to be public and served over https - Alexa just uses provided link as it is.

Same problem can be found by Flash Briefing creators - since flash briefing audio file also should have a public access. But - you can restrict access to your audio streams for [AWS IP range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) - found in Flash Briefing related [topic](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/comments/84743/view.html) on on [Amazon Developers Forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com). It won't secure your audio in 100% - but still can make your file not accessible from the 'rest of the Internet'.

Answer (score -1):

I also found out that it amazon did not play my mp3 unless the URL it was CA-signed. It didnt work with self-signed certificates.
An alternative would be to upload the mp3 file to Amazon S3 storage, there you can have more authentication mechanisms in place